# Movie texture not rendering?

Tags: texturing

I'm trying to render a movie on a plane. However, in the final render and viewport render, it only appears as the default grey plane. Settings are as follows.
[image]

[image]

Do I need to set up a material for it?

Answer (score 1):

You've set up a "brush" texture instead of a material texture, as you can read from the first drop down menu of your screenshot. 
Select your plane, create a new material for it and assign the movie as material color texture.